# Dimension Reduction with SVD in R

Tags: r, svd

I am trying to use SVD in R for dimension Reduction of a Matrix. I am able to find D, U, V matrix for "MovMat" Matrix. I want to reduce some dimensions that their values in D matrix is less than a "treshhold".
I wrote the code below. But I do not know how I can find values less than threshold in "MovMat" Matrix.

```
library(cluster)
library(fpc)

# "MovMat" is a users-movies Matrix. 
# It is contain the rating score which each user gives for each movie.
svdAllDimensions = svd(MovMat)
d=diag(svd$d) # Finding D, U, V
u=svd$u
v=svd$v
```

Comment: A reproducible example would likely help your chances of getting an answer. As it stands, it just sounds like you are just asking how to test for `d < threshold`, but I'm guessing (?) you know how to  do that...

Comment: My problem is in R programming language. I know that how can I do it in theory. For example I do not know how can I delete column which all its value is zero.

Comment: Here's how you might do that in R. First, to create an example matrix and threshold, do this `set.seed(1); m <- diag(runif(5)); thresh <- 0.5`.  Then look at your matrix, its diagonal, etc. `m; diag(m); diag(m) < thresh; diag[diag < thresh]`. Looking at those should help you see why this,  the answer to your question, works: `diag(m)[diag(m)<thresh] <- 0; m`.

Answer (score 1):

I assigned the values of D which is less than the Threshold and again multiply D, V, U with each other and find new matrix with less dimension.

```
  for(i in rowOfD){
   for(j in columnOfD){
     if (i==j){
      if(d[i,j]<Threshold){
       d[i,j] = 0
      }   
     }
   }   
 }
```

Comment: Horribly inefficient R code. Why not just:  `d[d<Threshold] <- 0` which seems to be what you describe or `d[d<Threshold & (col(d) == row(d) )] <- 0` which seems to be what the code is doing.